# Использование PDO в классах

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Здравствуйте, появилась проблема, решил подключить pdo к классам, но что-то не получается, вот процедурка:

```
$db = new DB($hostname,$user,$password,$db);
$db->connect();
$sql = $db->db->query('SELECT * FROM module');
$sql->execute();
```

а вот теперь у нас класс test, и мы вызываем метод test, в котором

```
function test()
{
        $sql = $db->db->query('SELECT * FROM module');
        $sql->execute();
}
```

можно конечно наследовать класс DB, и в test конструкт передать заново данные для подключения, но так делать плохо. Ребят кто то посоветует?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@АЛСУ](/users/13798/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%83) [вот](http://simple_pdo_implementation.onlinephpfunctions.com/) реализация которая вам нужна

Answer (score 1):

```
$db = new PDO(...);
```

Comment: #mountpoint
и что мне постоянно, когда я подключаю новый класс, заново подключаться к бд?

Comment: $db = new PDO(...);

class tralala {
    private $db;
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}

Comment: @АЛСУ, http://pastebin.com/PaS3Ta32

читайте мануалы http://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.pdo.php

Comment: это понятно, только у меня пдо вызывается из файла
$db = new DB($hostname,$user,$password,$db);
вот так, а когда я наследую свой класс, вызывается конструктор и в него не прихоядт праметры

Comment: @АЛСУ, залей код на http://pastebin.com, посмотрим что у тебя там

Comment: #mountpoint
вот ик
http://dumpz.org/647384/

Comment: @АЛСУ для вас есть выход называется [Singleton](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))

Comment: @АЛСУ у вас же переменная $db - глобальная.

Comment: @lampa, global $db; в классе прокатит?

Comment: #mountpoint
 не, это плохой тон, а в более новых версиях пхп вообще уберут global
если можете, приведите пример Singleton PDO

Comment: я уже понял сам)) поробуй лучше в класс N при создании его объекта передать $db, в кострукторе ловить и устанавливать новое свойство. А потом используй его как хочешь

Comment: @АЛСУ - в википедии же есть пример класса синглтона, наследуйте его.

Answer (score -1):

Я обычно в таких случаях делаю **global**, чтобы внутри функции видели эту переменную

```
function test()
{
    global $db;
    $sql = $db->db->query('SELECT * FROM module');
    $sql->execute();
}
```

Comment: @IVsevolod а если таких переменных 10 и более, в каждой функции писать global и перечислять переменные через запятую? Не зря придумали static(http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.static.php) и им нужно пользоваться!

Comment: А если я захочу переименовать переменную $db в другое название? А если вы делаете модуль, где переменная не $db, а у вашего знакомого она называется $db_one, что делать в этом случае?)

Comment: @Palmervan конечно, static не зря придумывали, и возможно здесь это будет красивее... Но с горящими глазами использовать во всех местах этот статик тоже не дело :)